# what the dns-loop-detect actually do?

Tags: dnsmasq

in one upstream dnsmasq (D1) I have:

```
log-queries
dns-loop-detect
server=/mydomain.net/192.168.200.1
```

in another dnsmasq (D2) I have:

```
log-queries
dns-loop-detect
domain=mydomain.net
...
```

When I `dig test.mydomain.net A` it works fine. However, if I do `dig test.mydomain.net AAAA`, B forwards the request back to D1 since I did not setup ipv6. Then the loop happens requests bounce between D1 and D2. I thought the dns-loop-detect will prevent this loop but it does not. I knew I can put local=/mydomain.net/ in D2 to prevent this. But what is the purpose of the dns-loop-detect then? What kind of loop it suppose to detect and stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That loop detection algorithm just send a simple probe to all upstreams *not* being limited to a specific domain (including rDNS).
If that probe is received back, the server id mentioned in that probe is marked as a loop (i.e. is skipped when checking for a usable upstream).

The most obvious loop it is meant and able to stop is when some resolvconf-related automation feeds dnsmasq all known dns servers - including dnsmasq itself in a role as local caching resolver.

The reason behind only sending the probes to upstreams valid for any domain is simply that the probe is a query for the name `test` - dnsmasq does not send such query to an upstream expressly not configured to handle arbitrary names.